# SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck at this error for a few days and still couldn't figure out what is wrong. Would be great if someone could just point me to the right direction of solving this issue.

**Update:**
I realise that error is gone when I commented "addMessages(xml)" in the updateMsg() function. How do I make it work then?

**Error:**
http://i.imgur.com/91HGTpl.png

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msg = $("#msg");
    var log = $("#log");
    var timestamp = 0;

    $("#name").focus();

    $("#login").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (!name) {
            alert("Please enter a name!");
            return false;
        }

        var username = new RegExp('^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$');

        if (!username.test(name)){
            alert("Invalid user name! \n Please do not use the following characters \n `~!@#$^&*()=|{}':;',\\[\\].<>/?~@#");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {name: name},
            success: function() {
                $(".login").hide();
            }
        })
        return false;
    });

    $("#form").submit(function() {
        if (!msg.val()) {
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_message.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {message: msg.val()},
        })

        msg.val("");

        return false

    });

    window.setInterval(function () {
        updateMsg();
    }, 300);

    function updateMsg() {
        $.post('server.php', {datasize: '1024'}, function(xml) {
            addMessages(xml);
        });
    }

    function addMessages(xml) {

        var json = eval('('+xml+')');

        $.each(json, function(i, v) {

            tt = parseInt(v.time);

               if (tt > timestamp) {
                console.log(v.message);
                appendLog($("<div/>").text('[' + v.username + ']' + v.message));
                timestamp = tt
            }
        });
    }

    function appendLog(msg) {
        var d = log[0]
        var doScroll = d.scrollTop == d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight;
        msg.appendTo(log)
        if (doScroll) {
            d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not fluent in javascript, but you have a semicolon after your first function `};` close bracket. Not sure if that would cause the error.

Comment: console log `xml` to see what your returned data is - `console.log(xml);`

Comment: @Rasclatt the semicolon wouldn't cause the error, but you're right, in this case it is not appropriate to put a `};`.  If you are defining an anonymous function as a variable, then `};` is appropriate. (i.e, `var f = function(){};`)

Comment: Yeah I tried it on my computer and it didn't throw any error.

Comment: So what **exactly** does `client.js` look like?

Comment: You can validate your JS here: http://www.jslint.com/..And where is your `addMessages`?

Comment: According to the image you posted, your client.js file consists of `()`. Is client.js supposed to contain the code you posted in the question?

Comment: @redbmk yes the code i posted is client.js

Comment: @phil I've updated it with what exactly does client.js looks like.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are calling `eval('(' + xml + ')')`. `xml` must be an empty string. Where is it coming from and what are you trying to do with it? `eval` is typically meant to run a piece of code and is generally not a good idea. What kind of data are you expecting from `server.php`?

Comment: @redbmk the following is the code to server.php
`<?php`
`$f = fopen("chatroom.xml", "r");`
`$info = fgets($f);`
`echo $info;`
`fclose($f);`
`?>`

Comment: try to remove the comma in data: {message: msg.val()}, <----
in the form submit ajax

Comment: OK, could you post some example content of `chatroom.xml`?

Comment: @katrin I just tried doing that but it doesn't seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @redbmk chatroom.xml is an empty file. Should there be anything inside? I'm sorry but I'm really new to web programming.

Comment: Yeah, right now you're basically trying to execute any code that is in `chatroom.xml`. It should contain some kind of useful information that your server should convert into JSON. Then in javascript you should use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval` to get something you can use. I posted an answer with some more detail and some reading material

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to [read up on eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) a bit. It looks like it doesn't do what you think it does.

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller.

Also

> There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to eval() for common use-cases.

It looks like what you're trying to do is get data from the server in the form of JSON. You'll need to make sure that your server returns something that is valid JSON, which you can verify [here](http://www.jslint.com/). Most server-side programming languages have a library that will turn an object into JSON to make that a piece of cake. [Here's an example for php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

On the client-side, you'll need to change `var json = eval('(' + xml + ')');` to `var json = JSON.parse(xml);` This will give you the javascript version of your php/perl/python/etc object. If it's an array, you can then iterate through it with a `for` loop, `Array.prototype.forEach`, or a variety of functions from different libraries, such as `$.each` or `_.each`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using eval is terribly wrong in this case and this answer fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' usually cause by something like

```
exeFunction(a,b,)
```

See if your form submit function ajax causing such error

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    if (!msg.val()) {
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'add_message.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {message: msg.val()},     <-------
    })

    msg.val("");

    return false

});
```

Comment: I tried removing the comma but it doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are triggering the java script on click or trigger any click. sometimes missing of 0 gives the above error.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">delete</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

would JSON.stringify({datasize: '1024'}) do the trick?  just a guess

Comment: No, jQuery transforms the data object into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format for use in the POST body. OP hasn't indicated this is a problem at all

Comment: k.. good to know.  I have learned to stringify every model that gets passed into jQuery ajax calls or it doesn't work for me.. quite possible that's related to the web api i talk to.. why i said it was a guess.